# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status while compiling

Tags: 20.04, gcc, makefile

first i want to say that i looked for every solution for this problem in the site ,but no luck !

i have a project which i'm trying to compile , when i compile it on Ubuntu 14 everything is ok , but when i try to compile the same project on ubuntu 18 or 20 i get the following error :

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or to be more specific this is what i get when running the command "make target=x64":

```
make target=x64
gcc -o x64/multics -s -ggdb3 -m64 -O3 -I. -fpack-struct -DCHECK_NEXTDCW -DSID_FILTER -DNEWCACHE -DCCCAM_CLI -DRADEGAST_CLI -DCAMD35_CLI -DCS378X_CLI -DHTTP_SRV -DTELNET -DMGCAMD_SRV -DCCCAM_SRV -DCAMD35_SRV -DCS378X_SRV -DEXPIREDATE -DDCWSWAP -DCACHEEX -DIPLIST -DTESTCHANNEL -DTHREAD_DCW -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_CCCAM -DEPOLL_MGCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM -DPEERLIST -DECMLIST -DFREECCCAM_SRV -DEPOLL_FREECCCAM -DGIT_COMMIT=\"NANO-E0-beta\" -DSRV_CSCACHE -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM x64/sha1.o x64/des.o x64/md5.o x64/aes.o x64/dcw.o x64/convert.o x64/tools.o x64/debug.o x64/parser.o x64/ipdata.o x64/threads.o x64/sockets.o x64/msg-newcamd.o x64/msg-cccam.o x64/msg-radegast.o x64/config.o x64/ecmdata.o x64/httpserver.o x64/telnet.o x64/main.o -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cache_setdcw':
/root/multics/x64/../clustredcache.c:1542: undefined reference to `isnullDCW'
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cache_fetch_samechannel':
/root/multics/x64/../clustredcache.c:1425: undefined reference to `isnullDCW'
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cache_pipe_recvmsg':
/root/multics/x64/../clustredcache.c:2368: undefined reference to `isnullDCW'
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cache_thread':
/root/multics/x64/../clustredcache.c:2725: undefined reference to `cache_recvmsg'
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cc_cli_recvmsg':
/root/multics/x64/../srv-cccam.c:1116: undefined reference to `cc_cli_parsemsg'
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cacheex_pipe_recvmsg':
/root/multics/x64/../cacheex.c:294: undefined reference to `cacheex_push'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/multics/x64/../cacheex.c:279: undefined reference to `cacheex_push'
/usr/bin/ld: x64/main.o: in function `cc_srv_recvmsg':
/root/multics/x64/../cli-cccam.c:392: undefined reference to `checkECMD5'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/multics/x64/../cli-cccam.c:395: undefined reference to `cacheex_check'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:166: link] Error 1
```

And here is the content of the Makefile:

```
GIT_VERSION := NANO-E0-$(shell git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags)

OPTS = -DCHECK_NEXTDCW -DSID_FILTER -DNEWCACHE \
        -DCCCAM_CLI -DRADEGAST_CLI -DCAMD35_CLI -DCS378X_CLI \
        -DHTTP_SRV -DTELNET -DMGCAMD_SRV -DCCCAM_SRV -DCAMD35_SRV -DCS378X_SRV \
        -DEXPIREDATE -DDCWSWAP -DCACHEEX -DIPLIST -DTESTCHANNEL -DTHREAD_DCW \
        -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_CCCAM -DEPOLL_MGCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM -DPEERLIST \
            -DECMLIST -DFREECCCAM_SRV -DEPOLL_FREECCCAM \
            -DGIT_COMMIT=\"$(GIT_VERSION)\" -DSRV_CSCACHE
        ## -DEPOLL_CACHE 
        ## -DTESTCHANNEL -DDEBUG_NETWORK -DDEBUG_NETWORK2 -DMONOTHREAD_ACCEPT  
        ## -DRADEGAST_SRV  -DFREECCCAM_SRV -DEPOLL_CACHE
        ## -DMULTICONNECT -DRECVMSG_BLOC -DIPLIST
        ## -DCLI_CSCACHE -DSRV_CSCACHE



ifeq ($(target),x32)
  CC        = gcc
  OUTPUT    = x32
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -m32 -O3 -I. $(OPTS) -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM -std=gnu90
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),x64)
  CC        = gcc
  OUTPUT    = x64
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -m64 -O3 -I. -fpack-struct $(OPTS) -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),ppc-old)
  CC        = /root/Desktop/tuxbox-cvs/root/cdk/bin/powerpc-tuxbox-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = ppc-old
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DINOTIFY -DSTB
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),ppc)
  CC        = /opt/powerpc-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin/powerpc-linux-gcc
  OUTPUT    = ppc
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DINOTIFY -DSTB
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),mipsel)
  CC        = /opt/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = mipsel
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -EL -march=mips1
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),mipsel-pli4)
  CC        = /opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = mipsel-pli4
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),sparc)
  CC        = sparc-linux-gnu-gcc-4.7
  OUTPUT    = sparc
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),sparc64)
  CC        = sparc64-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = sparc64
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),sh4)
  CC        = /opt/STM/STLinux-2.4/devkit/sh4/bin/sh4-linux-gcc
  OUTPUT    = sh4
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DST_7201 -DST_OSLINUX  -DARCHITECTURE_ST40 -DSTB -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),rpi)
#  CC        = /opt/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
  CC        = gcc
  OUTPUT    = rpi
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM -DNOPACK
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else

ifeq ($(target),arm-coolstream)
  CC        = /opt/arm-cx2450x-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-cx2450x-linux-gnueabi-gcc
  OUTPUT    = arm-coolstream
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -fPIC
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),mips-uclibc)
  CC        = /opt/cross-compiler-mips/bin/mips-gcc
  OUTPUT    = mips-uclibc
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -fPIC
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),armeb)
  CC        = /opt/OpenWrt-SDK-ixp4xx-2.6-for-Linux-i686/staging_dir_armeb/bin/armeb-linux-uclibc-gcc
  OUTPUT    = armeb
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DINOTIFY -DSTB
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),aarch64)
  CC        = aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = aarch64
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),fritzbox)
  CC        = /opt/gcc-4.2.1-uClibc-0.9.29/mipsel-linux-uclibc/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc-4.2.1
  OUTPUT    = fritzbox
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else

ifeq ($(target),mips64)
  CC        = mips64-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = mips64
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),ppc64el)
  CC        = powerpc64le-linux-gnu-gcc
  OUTPUT    = ppc64el
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS) -DSTB -DEPOLL_NEWCAMD -DEPOLL_ECM
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
else
ifeq ($(target),win32)
  CC        = /usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-gcc
  OUTPUT    = win32
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O2 $(OPTS)
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS) -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x0501 -lws2_32 -lpthread --disable-stdcall-fixup -mno-cygwin
else
  CC        = gcc
  OUTPUT    = x
  CFLAGS    = -s -ggdb3 -O3 -m64 -I. -fpack-struct $(OPTS) -D_GNU_SOURCE # -DSIG_HANDLER ## -DRECVMSG_BLOCK ## -DICACHE # -DCACHEEX_CWCYCLE ##  ##  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 
  LFLAGS    = $(CFLAGS)
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif

ifndef name
    NAME    = multics
else
    AOUT    = $(name)
endif


OBJECTS = $(OUTPUT)/sha1.o $(OUTPUT)/des.o $(OUTPUT)/md5.o $(OUTPUT)/aes.o \
    $(OUTPUT)/dcw.o $(OUTPUT)/convert.o $(OUTPUT)/tools.o $(OUTPUT)/debug.o $(OUTPUT)/parser.o $(OUTPUT)/ipdata.o \
    $(OUTPUT)/threads.o $(OUTPUT)/sockets.o $(OUTPUT)/msg-newcamd.o $(OUTPUT)/msg-cccam.o $(OUTPUT)/msg-radegast.o $(OUTPUT)/config.o \
    $(OUTPUT)/ecmdata.o $(OUTPUT)/httpserver.o $(OUTPUT)/telnet.o $(OUTPUT)/main.o

link: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT)/$(NAME) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -lpthread
    cp $(OUTPUT)/$(NAME) multics/$(NAME).$(OUTPUT)

%.o: ../%.c Makefile common.h config.h ecmdata.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OUTPUT)/httpserver.o: httpserver.h httpbuffer.c httpserver.c

$(OUTPUT)/main.o: main.c Makefile common.h httpserver.h config.h clustredcache.c cacheex.c pipe.c pipe.h \
    th-ecm.c th-cfg.c th-dns.c th-date.c th-srv.c \
    srv-cccam.c srv-newcamd.c srv-mgcamd.c srv-radegast.c srv-freecccam.c srv-camd35.c srv-cs378x.c \
    cli-common.c cli-cccam.c cli-newcamd.c cli-radegast.c cli-camd35.c cli-cs378x.c

all:
    $(MAKE) target=ppc-old
    $(MAKE) target=ppc
    $(MAKE) target=mipsel
    $(MAKE) target=mipsel-pli4
    $(MAKE) target=sh4
    $(MAKE) target=sparc
    $(MAKE) target=arm-coolstream
    $(MAKE) target=rpi
    $(MAKE) target=fritzbox
    $(MAKE) target=armeb
    $(MAKE) target=aarch64
    $(MAKE) target=ppc64el

clean:
    -rm $(OUTPUT)/*

cleanall:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) target=x64 clean
    $(MAKE) target=x32 clean
    $(MAKE) target=ppc-old clean
    $(MAKE) target=ppc clean
    $(MAKE) target=mipsel clean
    $(MAKE) target=mipsel-pli4 clean
    $(MAKE) target=sh4 clean
    $(MAKE) target=sparc clean
    $(MAKE) target=arm-coolstream clean
    $(MAKE) target=rpi clean
    $(MAKE) target=fritzbox clean
    $(MAKE) target=armeb clean
    $(MAKE) target=aarch64 clean
    $(MAKE) target=ppc64el clean
    -rm multics/*
```

so why the same project compilation works without any problem on Ubuntu 14 and cause error on Ubuntu 18 & 20 , Am i missing something ?!

Regards